# incompatible input shape while using DENet algorithm in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

See the example [link to DENet](https://github.com/MiviaLab/DENet)

It says

```
seq_len = 10 # number of frames in the sequence

samples = 400 # frame_size * sample_rate

input_shape = (seq_len, samples, 1)
```

I have used Librosa to read audio files and since librosa converts sample rate to 22050.
My X_train is of shape (6985,40) and model expectation is like this:

```
model = get_denet(input_shape, n_classes, sr=sample_rate, before_pooling=False)
```

but when I set input_shape to (6985,40) then it throws this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py in merge_with(self, other)
    845       try:
--> 846         self.assert_same_rank(other)
    847         new_dims = []

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py in assert_same_rank(self, other)
    890         raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s must have the same rank" % (self,
--> 891                                                                        other))
    892 

ValueError: Shapes (?, 40) and (?, ?, ?) must have the same rank

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py in with_rank(self, rank)
    920     try:
--> 921       return self.merge_with(unknown_shape(rank=rank))
    922     except ValueError:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py in merge_with(self, other)
    851       except ValueError:
--> 852         raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are not compatible" % (self, other))
    853 

ValueError: Shapes (?, 40) and (?, ?, ?) are not compatible

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py in __init__(self, input_shape, filter_shape, padding, strides, dilation_rate, name, data_format)
    912     try:
--> 913       input_shape.with_rank(num_spatial_dims + 2)
    914     except ValueError:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py in with_rank(self, rank)
    922     except ValueError:
--> 923       raise ValueError("Shape %s must have rank %d" % (self, rank))
    924 

ValueError: Shape (?, 40) must have rank 3

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18800/1890434596.py in <module>
----> 1 model = get_denet(input_shape, n_classes, sr=sample_rate, before_pooling=False)

~\Desktop\Audio Progress\DENet\denet\__init__.py in get_denet(input_shape, n_classes, sr, before_pooling, dropout)
     15 
     16     # SincNet Layer
---> 17     x = TimeDistributed(SincConv1D(80, 251, sr))(inp)
     18 
     19     attention_layer = DELayer(sum_channels=True, dropout=dropout)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    455             # Actually call the layer,
    456             # collecting output(s), mask(s), and shape(s).
--> 457             output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
    458             output_mask = self.compute_mask(inputs, previous_mask)
    459 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\keras\layers\wrappers.py in call(self, inputs, training, mask)
    246                 inner_mask_shape = self._get_shape_tuple((-1,), mask, 2)
    247                 kwargs['mask'] = K.reshape(mask, inner_mask_shape)
--> 248             y = self.layer.call(inputs, **kwargs)
    249             if hasattr(y, '_uses_learning_phase'):
    250                 uses_learning_phase = y._uses_learning_phase

~\Desktop\Audio Progress\DENet\denet\layers.py in call(self, x)
    152             x,
    153             kernel=filters,
--> 154             padding="same",
    155         )
    156 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in conv1d(x, kernel, strides, padding, data_format, dilation_rate)
   3609         strides=(strides,),
   3610         padding=padding,
-> 3611         data_format=tf_data_format)
   3612 
   3613     if data_format == 'channels_first' and tf_data_format == 'NWC':

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py in convolution(input, filter, padding, strides, dilation_rate, name, data_format)
    848         dilation_rate=dilation_rate,
    849         name=name,
--> 850         data_format=data_format)
    851     return op(input, filter)
    852 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py in __init__(self, input_shape, filter_shape, padding, strides, dilation_rate, name, data_format)
    914     except ValueError:
    915       raise ValueError(
--> 916           "input tensor must have rank %d" % (num_spatial_dims + 2))
    917 
    918     try:

ValueError: input tensor must have rank 3
```

Comment: Is `seq_len` 40  and `samples` 6985 in your case?

Comment: My every audio file is of 4 seconds so seq_len will be 4? and yes samples are 6985 that are stored in X_train

Comment: And what is 40?

Comment: 40 is the number of input features

Comment: Ok, but then your input shape is actually: `(samples=6985, seq_len=4, features=40)`?